Incoming/Outgoing graph is empty in one repo but not in another
The Source Control pane of one of my projects looks like this:

That is, the Incoming/Outgoing graph is empty.
In another project, however, it looks like this:

That is, it does show an Incoming/Outgoing graph.
As far as I can tell (I might be wrong, though, so feel free to tell me what to check), for both projects the following is true:

There have been multiple commits to the current branch since it was branched off master.
All commits have been pushed to the remote - i.e., the current branch is in sync with the remote.
The local and remote master branches are up-to-date and in sync.
There have been no commits to the master branch since the current branch was branched off it.
VSCode has the same settings for both projects.

My question is - what is causing the difference? Why is the graph present for one of the repos but not for the other? Please note that I am not asking how to turn off the graph - I know how to do it and don't want it done. I'm just asking what is causing it to be present or not. There must be some difference in the state of the two repos that VSCode is using to decide whether to show the graph or not.
P.S. In the latest version of VSCode (1.93.0), where they moved the Incoming/Outgoing graph to a separate view, all my projects have such a graph, so I assume that it must have been some kind of bug in the previous versions of VSCode.
